# PHP exec giving error while the command runs successfully in bat file

Tags: php, windows, apache, wampserver

I am running a local WAMP on my Windows 7 with a PHP script that executes a windows command as follows:

```
`exec('"%CD%\files_for_redistribution\ppt2html5.exe" /i:"%CD%\test.ppt" /o:"%CD%\output.html" /title:title /desc:description /author:author /keywords:keywords',$output,$error);`
```

The command when run from a batch file does the job well but when run from PHP script, gives an error:Presentation opening error: PowerPoint could not open the file.

The intention of the command is to convert PowerPoint to HTML using a third party software called ppt2html5.exe where test.ppt has to be converted to output.html.

I have found lot of blogs discussing about exec function not working properly but nothing really helped me to deal with this error as it runs the command but cannot open the file.
It would be great if somebody could help me with this.

Comment: I feel chills down my spine when I see people use the exec command :) - this is a side note but you should be aware that the exec command is a dangerous one and if exploited can resolve in one big hole of a security issue. Back to the issue. Are you sure the path is correct when running it from PHP?

Comment: The path is correct as it does the job when run as a batch file. Users would not be involved in the process and it runs on a local windows machine and so there would not be any security issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a folder named Desktop inside C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.

Source:http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?956457-Windows-2008-PHP-new-COM%28powerpoint-application%29

Answer (score 0):

Check if [safe mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) is on, because that activates [escapeshellcmd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) and some characters are escaped.

Assuming that the string that you are passing to exec(), including percentage signs, routes and parameters are right, your problem may be related to permission of files and user executing apache + php, check that.

Comment: Safe mode is not on. As far as permissions are concerned, the file is not read only and so that is not the reason. I fetched the contents of the file by using file_get_contents which means the script is able to open the file and read it.

Comment: Also, if I run a batch file having the same command with php exec instead of writing the command directly into the exec function, I still get the same error. But if that batch file is run independantly there are no issues and it does the job.